Neo4j CALL {} IN TRANSACTIONS Does Not Work in Neo4j HTTP API
According to this https://neo4j.com/docs/http-api/current/transactions/, neo4j transactions cannot be used in explicit transactions and need to be sent as implicit transactions.
However, after following the instructions I still get the same error. I'm using neo4j version 4.4.3 and running this first to create a transaction.
http://localhost:7474/db/neo4j/tx/commit


curl --location 'http://localhost:7474/db/neo4j/tx/commit' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--header 'Accept: application/json; charset=UTF-8' \
--data '{
  "statements": [
    {
      "statement": "LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'file.csv' AS row CALL {with row MERGE (movie:Movies {orderid: row.orderid}) SET movie.name =row.name } IN TRANSACTIONS OF 1000 ROWS"
    },


The error after running the second API call:
The query is simplified for the sake of this question. I've also tried calling neo4j http API with /transaction/commit endpoint but that also throws the same error. Not sure if it's due to versions but the documentation says 5.x. Is there a way to execute implicit transactions as part of neo4j http api calls? My environment limits my options to use neo4j driver as I think all of this would be much easier via driver.
Removing the "IN TRANSACTIONS' make it work but I need to write large volume of data and need it to make it more scalable.
Update: Making the transaction implicit according to the doc still threw the same error
This is how you make implicit requests in HTTP API.
http://localhost:7474/db/neo4j/tx/commit

The error message is pretty explanatory, you need to use implicit and not explicit transactions. Five seconds googling lead you to the right section in the Neo4j documentation https://neo4j.com/docs/http-api/current/query/

@ChristopheWillemsen even though the error message is pretty explanatory, the document itself is not when it comes to versioning. I had a longer discussion about this in the neo4j community if you'd like to take a look. My finding is that Call{} in transactions are not supported in neo4j 4.4.3 "IF" the request is made through neo4j's HTTP API. "Even if the request is implicit" https://community.neo4j.com/t/neo4j-call-in-transactions-does-not-work-in-neo4j-http-api/71268/10

@ChristopheWillemsen the question is updated for better alignment with the issue I've described. However,if you look at the op you'll see that I also tried calling it with an implicit endpoint that you found so easily in 5 seconds and it still was the same result.

CALL IN TRANSACTIONS doesn't exist in Neo4j 4.4.x

@ChristopheWillemsen it actually does according to this doc https://neo4j.com/product/neo4j-graph-database/whats-new-in-neo4j-4-4/...
the problem is neo4j call IN transactions only works in neo4j browser or with neo4j driver (you also need to append :auto) for neo4j browser.
not in HTTP call, but like I said nothing in docs make this clear. The solution for me is to upgrade the neo4j version but that's not feasible. so I'm using periodic commit instead.
